# NavigationWindow class: remove navigation bar and maximized NavigationWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigationbar, navigationwindow

excuse me for my bad English.

I know that many conversations were made ​​for this type of problem but none answer my specific problem...
I am currently improving a Wpf Application coded in C # and xaml in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

I would like to remove the navigation bar at the top of my window and maximize it. In my xaml file I do:

```
        NavigationWindow x:Class="WpfAppTest.MainWindow"                  
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="980 " Width="540" Source="Home.xaml" />
```

Despite `WindowState= "Maximized"` and `WindowStyle="None"` the navigation bar is still displayed and the window is still small. I followed several tutorials that removed the navigation bar, but they used a Window class. I did some tests on a new project by creating a class Window and I can well maximize and remove the navigation bar from my window.
But in my case I need to improve an application in progress but the main window type is MainWindow

Indeed the source `Source= "Home.xaml"` is no longer recognized after the change Navigation Window to Window. My application contains several pages and I must navigate through it so I have to keep my "Home" type "page" page: `<Pagex:Class = "WpfAppTest.Home"`.
Do you have any idea where my problem may be?

Thanks you in advance.

Geoffrey

Answer (score 0):

You can host a `Frame` in your `Window`. That is essentially what a `NavigationWindow` does. 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#Navigation_Hosts) has more info on navigation hosts.